# HTML, I don't get why still need to put class="container" under class="nav"?

Tags: html, css

I don't get why still need to put class="container" under class="nav"? the class="nav" has already separate the whole element... why still need to put class="container"?

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Airbnb logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "need" ?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Please describe your question.

Comment: @Shubham Bhave pls. check my question again

Comment: There is no need put `class="container"`. You can use like `.nav > div` in css. And Why there is `class = nothing` in ul.  `<ul class = >`

Comment: it depends what you are trying to do. but generally no you wont.

Answer (score 0):

Why?

Because, in the absence of any other information, you might wish to restrict the width of the `.container` class but not that of the `.nav` class.

Perhaps you want the `.nav` to be 100% wide (which it would be by default) but the container to be 80% wide and centered.

That is just **one** reason...

Example Below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav {
  background: lightblue
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</div>
```